# Why wont my PHP MYSQL comparison work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, compare

Im messing around, trying to see if i can make one of those clickable pet sites that were all the rage a couple years ago and i run into a problem with trying to use if, else, elseif stuff in PHP.
Heres what I have:

```
<?php
include_once "mysql_connect.php";

$newip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$oldip = mysql_query("SELECT lastip FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='index'");

if ($newip == $oldip) {
$message = "You were the last one to click this pet, please wait until someone else has clicked it before trying again.";
}
else {
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `clicks` = `clicks`+1 WHERE name='index'");
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `lastip` = '$newip'  WHERE name='index'");
$tempclicks = mysql_query("SELECT `clicks` FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='index'");
$message = "You gave this pet a click!";
};
if ($tempclicks == 150) {
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `level` = 2 WHERE name='index'");
$message = "Your click leveled the pet up!";
}
elseif ($tempclicks == 600) {
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `level` = 3 WHERE name='index'");
$message = "Your click leveled the pet up!";
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='index'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$clicks = $row["clicks"];
$level = $row["level"];
$name = $row["name"];
$image1 = $row["image1"];
$image2 = $row["image2"];
$image3 = $row["image3"];
};
if ($level == 1) {
$imageu = $image1;
}
elseif ($level == 2) {
$imageu = $image2;
}
elseif ($level == 3) {
$imageu = $image3;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<?php print $oldip; ?> <br>
<?php print $newip; ?> <br>
Name: <?php print $name; ?> <br>
<img src=<?php print $imageu; ?> /> <br>
Clicks: <?php print $clicks; ?> <br>
Level: <?php print $level; ?> <br>
<?php print $message; ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the first problem i'm having is with comparing the users ip with the last ip that was on the page.

```
$newip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$oldip = mysql_query("SELECT lastip FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='index'");

if ($newip == $oldip) {
$message = "You were the last one to click this pet, please wait until someone else has clicked it before trying again.";
}
else {
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `clicks` = `clicks`+1 WHERE name='index'");
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `lastip` = '$newip'  WHERE name='index'");
$tempclicks = mysql_query("SELECT `clicks` FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='index'");
$message = "You gave this pet a click!";
};
```

No matter what i have tried it doesnt really compare the values. If i put a "=" it says theyre the same no matter what and if i do "==" it says theyre different even though they shouldn't be.

I dont even know where to start with this, no errors come up and i'm fairly new to PHP and MYSQL. Nothing else can be really tested until this, but im sure that the rest of the comparisons dont work either.

im using 000webhost for my site, if thats known to have problems lol

Comment: Where to start? A single `=` is an assignment, not a comparison, so `==` or possibly `===` is what you need. Your comparisons fail because you're not fetching the results of your query, nor are you checking the result for errors, and you're using a deprecated API anyway. Find a good tutorial based on `mysqli` or `PDO` and follow it. This is too broad for [so]

Comment: I'm leaning towards saying that this code seems to check out, however I'm under the impression that your server may no longer be supporting the older `mysql_` functions. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: haha Thanks for the input guys, I've been browsing tutorials and its hard to find what i need, I noticed all the updates so i thought something like this might happen.

Comment: As for `if ($newip == $oldip)` - `WHERE name='index'` would need to be a unique entry from that row. If there are other of the same, then that could be an issue. Plus, 000webhost does support `mysql_` so your query may be failing somewhere.

Comment: The thing is that, yes, it works for grabbing the information and printing it (the bottom of the code), but it does not work for comparing.

Comment: This is what I don't get. You've a whole bunch of `WHERE name='index'` and you're wanting to find if an old IP matches the new IP. You should be doing something like `WHERE ip='$newip'` - "ip" column being an example of course. Maybe even adding another clause. `WHERE ip='$newip' AND other_column='something'`. As I mentioned earlier, check for errors and use `var_dump()` to see what's passing through or not and echo your query also.

Comment: Using the soon-to-be-removed MySQL code, I finally got it working. I went back and rewrote everything and somehow came out on top. Thanks for your help, I'll have to take some time to learn the improved coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my code looks like now, it works too so im done here:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$name = $_POST['name'];
if (empty($name) == true){
$name = "index";
};

include_once "mysql_connect.php";
$newip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$lastip = $row["lastip"];
}
if ($lastip == $newip) {
$message = "You were the last one to click this pet! You have to wait until someone else clicks it!";
} else {
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `clicks` = `clicks`+1 WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `lastip` = '$newip' WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
$message = "You clicked the pet!";
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$clicks = $row["clicks"];
$level = $row["level"];
}

if ($clicks > 50*$level) {
mysql_query("UPDATE sitefunctions SET `level` = `level`+1 WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
$message = "Your click leveled up the pet!";
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sitefunctions WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$clicks = $row["clicks"];
$level = $row["level"];
$name = $row["name"];
$image1 = $row["image1"];
$image2 = $row["image2"];
$image3 = $row["image3"];
$lastip = $row["lastip"];
};
if ($level > 35) {
$imageu = $image3;
} elseif ($level > 15) {
$imageu = $image2;
} elseif ($level > 0) {
$imageu = $image1;
};
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<p>
Name: <?php print $name; ?> <br>
<img src=<?php print $imageu; ?> /> <br>
Clicks: <?php print $clicks; ?> <br>
Level: <?php print $level; ?> <br>
Last User: <?php print $lastip; ?> <br>
<?php print $message; ?>
</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```